# Isomorphism theorem and proving $f:G\to G'$ onto, $K'\triangleleft G'\Rightarrow G/f^{-1}(K')\cong G'/K'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We proved this using the first isomorphism theorem:

> Let $f:G\to G'$ be onto, $K'$ be any normal subgroup of $G'$and $K=\{x\in G|f(x)\in K'\}$ $=f^{-1}(K')$. Then $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/K$ is isomorphic to $G'/K'$.

In our book, it first takes a map $\phi$ from $G$ to $G'/K'$ and proves it is epimorphism, then applies the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms and we get $G/\ker \phi\cong G'/K'$ and a property of the fundamental theorem says that $\ker \phi=K$.

I want to ask: can't I first prove $K$ is normal in $G$, and then prove $G/K$ is isomorphic to $G'/K'$? I think I proved it successfully. If not, please give the reason.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is violating the most basic internet etiquette and formatting guidelines.

Comment: In your method you outline the steps as (1) prove $K$ is normal in $G$, (2) prove $G/K$ isomorphic to $G'/K'$. How do you plan on arguing (2)? It seems to be a direct application of the first isomorphism theorem. And in order to use it successfully we need to show $\ker\phi=K$, which automatically tells us $K$ is normal.

Comment: @anon Thank you for your (considerable) effort. Voted to reopen.